# Defer and fromCallable behavior in RxJava 2.x

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I've read some RxJava2 issues about the crash after call `dispose()` on an Observable [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4991) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4880). Then I tried to reproduce the crash by the code:

```
private String simulateHeavyWork() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    return "Done";
}
private void myFunc() {
    Disposable disposable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> simulateHeavyWork())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(System.out::println, throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage()));
   sleep(1000);
   disposable.dispose();

   sleep(60000);
}
```

When I ran the code, I got the exception `io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException` as expected. As the discussion in above link, RxJava2 will not swallow the Throwable so we have to [handle this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling). But when I tried to use the `defer` instead of `fromCallable` to create the Observable, surprised me, no error was fired.

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(simulateHeavyWork()))
```

It surprises me again when I use `Flowable` instead of `Observable`, the `UndeliverableException` happened again.

```
Disposable disposable = Flowable.defer(() -> Flowable.just(simulateHeavyWork()))
```

So I'm confusing about the difference between `defer` and `fromCallable`, `Flowable` and `Observable` in this case.

Comment: Please always make sure you run with the latest RxJava version. This particular inconsistency was fixed in [2.1.15](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases/tag/v2.1.15).

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, It's consistency in RxJava 2.1.15